# stable docs broadcast example fails

Tags: julia

In [the arrays section of the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/arrays/) there is an example of using implicit broadcast on strings which is failing for me. I can work around it, but I just wanted to report it -

```
julia> string.(1:3, ". ", ["First", "Second", "Third"])
```

I get the following output -

```
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching size(::String)
Closest candidates are:
  size{N}(::Any, ::Integer, ::Integer, ::Integer...) at abstractarray.jl:48
  size(::BitArray{1}) at bitarray.jl:39
  size(::BitArray{1}, ::Any) at bitarray.jl:43
  ...
 in map(::Base.#indices, ::Tuple{String,Array{String,1}}) at 
./tuple.jl:93
 in broadcast_shape(::UnitRange{Int64}, ::String, ::Array{String,1}, 
::Vararg{Array{String,1},N}) at ./broadcast.jl:31
 in broadcast_t(::Function, ::Type{T}, ::UnitRange{Int64}, 
::Vararg{Any,N}) at ./broadcast.jl:228
 in broadcast(::Function, ::UnitRange{Int64}, ::String, 
::Array{String,1}) at ./broadcast.jl:230
```

Comment: works here on 0.7. version?

Comment: Works here on v0.6. What does your `versioninfo()` say?

Comment: I am still on 0.5.1. Maybe it's time to upgrade! Thanks for the quick feedback.

Comment: Yup, dot broadcasting was much improved with v0.6

Answer (score 1):

It is just a version issue. On v0.5 it doesn't work and from v0.6 it does.

The docs are also appropriately versioned:

[version 0.5 Array broadcasting docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1)

[version 0.6 Array broadcasting docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.6/manual/arrays/#Broadcasting-1)

So all is good.